# PHP: empty doesn't work with a getter method

Tags: php, class, getter

I have a "getter" method like

```
function getStuff($stuff){
  return 'something';
}
```

if I check it with `empty($this->stuff)`, I always get `FALSE`, but I know `$this->stuff` returns data, because it works with echo.

and if I check it with `!isset($this->stuff)` I get the correct value and the condition is never executed...

here's the test code:

```
class FooBase{

  public function __get($name){
    $getter = 'get'.ucfirst($name);
    if(method_exists($this, $getter)) return $this->$getter();
    throw new Exception("Property {$getter} is not defined.");
  }
}

class Foo extends FooBase{
  private $my_stuff;

  public function getStuff(){
    if(!$this->my_stuff) $this->my_stuff = 'whatever';
    return $this->my_stuff;
  }

}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->stuff;

if(empty($foo->stuff)) echo 'but its not empty:(';
if($foo->stuff) echo 'see?';
```

Comment: my question is why doesn't empty() report the correct value in this case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`empty()` will call `__isset()` first, and only if it returns `true` will it call `__get()`.

Implement `__isset()` and make it return `true` for every magic property that you support.

```
function __isset($name)
{
    $getter = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
    return method_exists($this, $getter);
}
```

Comment: like this?   `public function __isset($name){
    $getter = 'get'.ucfirst($name);
    if(method_exists($this, $getter)) return true;
  }`

Comment: Judging from your example, yes, it seems it's the right way. I've updated my answer with a shorter version of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Magic getters are *not* called when checking with `empty`. The value really does not exist, so `empty` returns `true`. You will need to implement `__isset` as well to make that work correctly.

> `__isset()` is triggered by calling `isset()` or `empty()` on inaccessible properties.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Comment: I think it's a right answer. Also `empty` on functions gives us error, so formally current php behaviour has a bug, as it allows to calls empty on functions (even they are magic). Hmm... but they are magic. So, let it be not bug, but a feature.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [magic get method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) is named `__get()`. `$this->stuff` will not call `getStuff()`. Try this:

```
public function __get($property) {
    if ($property == 'stuff') {
        return $this->getStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: but I have that. I made a class with with two __get and __set functions that call my methods, and extended it.. And it works with `isset()` but not with `empty()` :(

Comment: Yes, posting the *actual* code that you're using is generally preferable to some example code that doesn't really do what you're *actually* doing. :)