# empty() returns wrong result

Tags: php

```
$user = new User(1);

var_dump($user->ID);
if (empty($user->ID))
    echo "empty";

// output string(2) "77" empty
```

So why is empty() returning `true` even when `$user` var is not empty?

The relevant parts of my User class:

```
class User {
    protected $data = null;

    public function __construct($userID) {
        // sql select
        $this->data = $sqlResult;
    }

    // ...

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name]))
            return $this->data[$name];
        else
            return null;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

So I updated my User class and added the __isset() method

```
public function __isset($name) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name]) && !empty($this->data[$name]))
                return true;
        else
                return false;
}
```

This leads me to another problem:
When calling `empty()` on my not empty var `empty($user->ID)` it will return false, but when using `isset($user->ID)` on a declared var which is empty (e.g. `$user->ID = ''`) it will also return false, because `isset()` will call `__isset()` inside the class, right?

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?
PHP notes, that I should copy the overloaded property into a local variable, which seems too much paperwork for me ;)

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241039/php-empty-doesnt-work-with-a-getter-method

Comment: it is evaluating to see if `ID` exists in the `User` class. It is case sensitive

Comment: thank you, that should solve my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`empty()` doesn't call `__get()`. You need to implement `__isset()`.

Comment: Good answer! You should consider to give a short example. Just for future reference.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it one more time! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get):

> **Note**:
>
> It is not possible to use overloaded properties in other language constructs than isset(). This means if empty() is called on an overloaded property, the overloaded method is not called.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it one more time! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, you should overload [__isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) for empty to work

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it one more time! Thanks!